# How to send total model object as a parameter of Alamofire post method in Swift3?

Tags: object, post, parameters, swift3, alamofire

I have a model class like this

```
class Example() {
  var name:String?
  var age:String?
  var marks:String? 
}
```

I'm adding data to that model class

```
let example = Example()
example.name = "ABC"
example.age = "10"
example.marks = "10"
```

After that I converted to JSON  then I posted

```
Alamofire.request(URL, method:.post, parameters: example)
```

Alamofire not accepting parameters only its accepting like `parameters = ["":"","",""]-->key value based`, so I tried to convert model to JSON, JSON to dictionary, even though not accepting its showing like parameters problem. Exactly I need total model object need to send as a parameter of post method in Alamofire like this:

```
let example = Example()
Alamofire.request(URL, method:.post, parameters: example)
```

Comment: i tried like this also

let json = SwiftyJSON.JSON(example)
 Alamofire.request(URL, method:.put, parameters:json, encoding:JSONEncoding.default, headers :Defines.Api.Headers ).responseJSON

not accepting

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: A good answer appears to have been added below, Tirupatirao, on the same day you asked this question. How did you get on with that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the Alamofire API is only accepting dictionaries, create a dictionary yourself!

Add a method in the model class called `toJSON`:

```
func toJSON() -> [String: Any] {
    return [
        "name": name as Any,
        "age": age as Any,
        "marks": marks as Any
    ]
}
```

Then call this method when calling `request`:

```
Alamofire.request(URL, 
    method:.put, 
    parameters:example.toJSON(), 
    encoding:JSONEncoding.default, 
    headers :Defines.Api.Headers )
```

Alternatively, use SwiftyJSON:

```
func toJSON() -> JSON {
    return [
        "name": name as Any,
        "age": age as Any,
        "marks": marks as Any
    ]
}
```

Usage:

```
Alamofire.request(URL, 
    method:.put, 
    parameters:example.toJSON().dictionaryObject, 
    encoding:JSONEncoding.default, 
    headers :Defines.Api.Headers )
```

Comment: i have `struct ProfilePassword: Encodable {
    private let pw: Password
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case pw = "password_update"
    } 
    private struct Password: Encodable {
        let password: String
        let confirmation: String
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case password = "password"
            case confirmation = "password_confirmation"}}
        init(_ password: String) {
        pw = Password(password: password, confirmation: password) }}`how do i send this model object as a parameter in alamofire?

Comment: There is nothing generic ? or we need to make it on each class that we want to post through API. I can't believe it

Comment: @theMouk Now we have the `Codable` API, which you can use to convert your object to `Data` and then send with Alamofire. But since this question is tagged swift3 and was posted ages ago, `Codable` wasn't available at that time.

Answer (score 1):

The best way so far is to make your model conform to `Encodable` then
convert you model into json Data like so

```swift
let data = try! JSONEncoder.init().encode(example)
```

then use `SwiftyJSON` to convert it back to `dictionary`

```swift
let json = try! JSON.init(data: data)
let dictionary = json.dictionaryObject
```

as Rob said you can also use `JSONSerialization` if you are not already using `SwiftyJSON`

```swift
let dictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String: Any]
```

Then use the `dictionary` in your parameters

Also Alamofire now supports Encodable parameters with

```swift
let urlRequest = JSONParameterEncoder.init().encode(example, into: urlRequest)
```

Comment: 1. If you want to use `JSONEncoder `, it needs to conform to `Encodable`, not `Decodable`. 2. If you use `JSONEncoder`, you don’t need that `init`, e.g., `let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(example)`. 3. I don’t think that introducing another library, such as SwiftyJSON, adds any value here, e.g. `let dictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String: Any]` is sufficient.

Comment: And, in the interest of full disclosure, that `JSONParameterEncoder` (which is a great improvement) is still only in the beta version of Alamofire. (And, again, the `init` is not needed, so you might do `let encoded = try! JSONParameterEncoder().encode(foo, into: request)`.)

Comment: I meant `Encodable` in the first place cause it's enough for the example as he will only need the encoding part of it.

Comment: The `init` is just a personal preference (a thing) that I like using instead of `()` and it's the same at the end.

Comment: and yes you are totally right about using `JSONSerialization` if SwiftyJSON was not already being used in the codebase.