# how to post single object as parameter in http request in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, post, swift3

I have test this link too. giving me bad request (400)

using native library not almafire

here is link i've cheeked
[send object as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43649027/how-to-send-total-model-object-as-a-parameter-of-alamofire-post-method-in-swift3?answertab=votes#tab-top)

please vote me up

here is my full code

```
guard let url=URL(string: "http://test.com/google/getAddress") else{return}

let parameters=GoogleMap()

var requst=URLRequest(url: url)
requst.httpMethod="POST"
requst.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
requst.httpMethod="POST"
guard let httpbody=try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: []) else{return}

requst.httpBody=httpbody

print(url)

let _=URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requst) { (data, response, error) in
    if let data=data{

        do{
            let json=try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)

            print(json)
        }
        catch{

            print(error)
        }
    }
    }.resume()
    }
```

my model class

```
class Model {

    private var latitude:Double?
    private var longitude:Double?

    var _latitude:Double{
        get{
            return latitude!
        }
        set{
            latitude=newValue
        }
    }

    var _longitude:Double{

        get{
            return longitude!
        }
        set{
            longitude=newValue
        }
    }

    func toJSON() -> [String: Any] {
        return [ "latitude": latitude as Any, "longtide": longitude as Any]
    }

}
```

I have tested as a dictionary but server gives me "bad request" error in its JSON response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your JSON is using the wrong key for the `longitude`. You're using `longtide`, which is obviously not what you intended. If you use `longitude`, it works fine.

---

A few unrelated observations:

1. You are doing `do`-`catch`, but don't have a `try`. You are using `try?` which doesn't throw any errors, but rather just returns `nil` if there was a problem. Therefore is nothing to catch. Use `try`, not `try?` if you want to catch the error.
2. You have a curious model object in which you have private properties, but then have computed properties that `get` and `set` the private property. If you're not doing anything valuable in your custom getter and setter, you should lose those computed properties entirely because this is just convoluted and inefficient. Plus the underscore convention is used for hidden, private properties, not for properties you expose.
3. One is left to infer that your `GoogleMap` method is returning a `[String: Any]` produced by `toJSON`. In Swift 4, you can use `JSONEncoder` and make your model object `Encodable` (or `Codable`), and you can avoid that `toJSON` method. Just change `GoogleMap` to return the simple model object which you can then encode with `JSONEncoder`.

So, that leaves us with:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://test.com/google/getAddress")!

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let coordinate = Coordinate(latitude: 34.05222, longitude: -118.242) // set this however you want
request.httpBody = try! JSONEncoder().encode(coordinate)

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error ?? "Unknown error")
        return
    }

    do {
        let responseObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
        print(responseObject)
    } catch let parseError {
        print(parseError)
    }
}.resume()
```

And your model object is reduced to merely:

```
struct Coordinate: Codable {
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
}
```

Or, if you really need it to be a reference type, a `class`:

```
class Coordinate: Codable {
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double

    init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
    }
}
```

---

If you're stuck in Swift 3, then go ahead and make a dictionary, but I'd make it `[String: Double]`, e.g.

```
let url = URL(string: "http://ipinbar.net:8080/google/getAddress")!

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let coordinate = Coordinate(latitude: 34.05222, longitude: -118.242) // set this however you want
request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: coordinate.dictionary)

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error ?? "Unknown error")
        return
    }

    do {
        let responseObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)

        print(responseObject)
    } catch let parseError {
        print(parseError)
    }
}.resume()
```

and

```
struct Coordinate {
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double

    var dictionary: [String: Double] { return ["latitude": latitude, "longitude": longitude] }
}
```

Comment: hey Rob.tnx a lot. I'm using swift 3 and I can't update to 4 now.would you help with this line of code:request.httpBody = try! JSONEncoder().encode(coordinate). in swift 3 ??The equivalent of the JSONEncoder()

Comment: @Ryan110 - Then that dictionary trick is fine, though the resulting model type is still a lot simpler than that original code snippet you supplied. ;) See expanded answer above.

Comment: you made my day...!! so there is question for your: why torsion() func not working but var dictionary works well.there for both are kinda same?

Comment: and tnx to those who were vote me down for not logical reason

Comment: @Ryan110 - Largely because, as I note in the beginning of my answer, I used `longitude` and you used `longtide` (you misspelled the name of the key). I think the casting of the optionals to `Any`, without unwrapping them, is dangerous, though I don’t think that was, technically, a problem.

Comment: tnx for being so kind Rob. my final question is I have a model class for parsed son.how can I parse my son into my model class?

Comment: class Google{
    
    init() {
        
    }
    
    let results:[results] = []
    
    let status:String = ""

    
}

Comment: First, it’s too bad that you can’t contemplate transitioning to Swift 4 (a breeze in comparison to the Swift 2 to 3 transition process), because it makes this stuff so much easier. Second, in Swift 3, my approach would be to parse the JSON into a dictionary and then manually navigate through it. I’d write a `init?(dictionary: [String: Any])` method to convert the dictionary into your model object. If you have more questions, you should probably post a new question rather than continuing more comments here, under an answer that is only peripherally related to these new questions.

Comment: Rob I know this is to a good place to ask a question but they vote me down and I'm limited for asking new question. would you help me with this??

Comment: my model class :class Google{
    
    var results:[Results]
    
    var status:String
    
    init(Json:[String:Any]) {
        
       status=Json["status"] as! String
       results=Json["results"] as! [Results]
        
    }

Comment: and I'm init it this way. :let c = Google(Json:responseObject).     but nil returns

Comment: will you remove url address from source code please ?

Comment: @Ryan110 - Done. And if that URL is highly confidential, you can "flag" your question for moderator attention to ask them to purge revision history for both your question and this answer, both of which have that URL in their respective revision histories.